# Entity framework mvc how can I use inner join?

Tags: c#, .net, join, linq-to-sql, devexpress

I am trying to develop a project with DevExpress mvc. I used Entity Framework for database connection. 
What I want to do is to combine two tables with a companyId in the c table and with a guId in the k table

what i want to do;  https://ekitapdfindir.com/istek.png

my Index View;

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<plate_logs>()
        .ShowBorders(true)
        .DataSource(d => d.WebApi().Controller("PlateLogs").Key("Guid"))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.AddFor(m => m.Guid).Width(100);
            columns.AddFor(m => m.LastUpdateDate).Width(90);
            // Columns Location ID
            columns.AddFor(m => m.LocationId)
                .Lookup(lookup =>
                    lookup
                    .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                        .Controller("Locations")
                        .LoadAction("Get")
                        .Key("adsad"))
                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                    .ValueExpr("Guid"));
            // Columns Gate ID
            columns.AddFor(m=>m.GateId)
                .Lookup(lookup => lookup
                    .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                        .Controller("Gates")
                        .LoadAction("Get")
                        .Key("GateId"))
                    .DisplayExpr("Name")
                    .ValueExpr("Guid"));
            // Columns Departmant ID
            columns.AddFor(m => m.DepartmentId)
               .Lookup(lookup => lookup
                   .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                       .Controller("Departments")
                       .LoadAction("Get")
                       .Key("DepartmentId"))
                   .DisplayExpr("Name")
                   .ValueExpr("Guid"));
            // Columns Driver ID 
            columns.AddFor(m => m.DriverId)
               .Lookup(lookup => lookup
                   .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                       .Controller("Driver")
                       .LoadAction("Get")
                       .Key("DriverId"))
                   .DisplayExpr("FullName")
                   .ValueExpr("Guid"));

            // Columns Company ID    
            columns.AddFor(m => m.DriverId)
               .Lookup(lookup => lookup
                   .DataSource(d => d.WebApi()
                       .Controller("Driver")
                       .LoadAction("Gets"))
                   .DisplayExpr("Name")
                   .ValueExpr("Guid"));

        })
        .Paging(p => p.PageSize(20))            
    )
)
```

my Driver Controller ;

```
        LCWCENTEREntities db = new LCWCENTEREntities();
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var model = db.driver.ToList();
            return Request.CreateResponse(DataSourceLoader.Load(model, loadOptions));
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Gets(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var sorgu = from d in db.driver
                        join c in db.company
                        on d.CompanyId equals c.Guid
                        select  new {d,c };
            return Request.CreateResponse(DataSourceLoader.Load(sorgu, loadOptions));
        }
```

The gets actions connects the driver table to the company table and sends the data to the viewer

### Edit

my plate_log table ;

```
    public partial class plate_logs
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long Guid { get; set; }
        public string Plate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> DriverId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> isRemoved { get; set; }
    }
```

driver table ;

```
    public partial class driver
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public long Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> isRemoved { get; set; }
    }
```

and company table;

```
    public partial class company
    {
        public short Id { get; set; }
        public long Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public Nullable<short> isSync { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<byte> isRemoved { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. But as a side note: shouldn't the condition be `on d.CompanyGuid equals c.Guid` instead of `d.CompanyId equals c.Guid`?

Comment: question edit sql database

Comment: You 're not really asking a question. What's the issue we can help with?

Comment: I wanted to draw the names from the company's table

Comment: That's still not a question. A typical Stack Overflow question should consist of four elements: what you want to achieve, what you tried, where you didn't succeed or got stuck, and a question asking how this *specific* problem can be solved. Your "question" lacks the last two elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. 
Driver controller edit ;

```
public HttpResponseMessage Gets(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var sorgu = (from c in db.company
                        join d in db.driver
                        on c.Guid equals d.CompanyId
                        orderby c.Guid descending
                        select new { Guid= d.Guid, Name=c.Name, });
            return Request.CreateResponse(DataSourceLoader.Load(sorgu.ToList(), loadOptions));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve is easy to do if you are using *Eager Loading* with the `Include` method. More info can be found [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/eager-loading-in-entity-framework.aspx).

This automatically generates LINQ behind the scene which brings the table in quest plus its requested related table. From what I see in your models I think that you also need to provide the Navigation Properties between the tables to define their relantionship.

So an example would be like:

### Models

```
public class A 
{
       public int PropertyA {get; set;}

       public B B {get; set;}
}
```

---

```
public class B 
{
       public int PropertyB {get; set;}

       public A A {get; set;}
}
```

---

In the controller you need to call the LINQ method with Include() now like

### Controller

```
context_variable.A.Include(x => x.B).ToList();
```

I hope this helps you, and is explanatory enough.